# Linux Kernel Module loading in Docker container - Runaway Usage

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

When starting a docker container on an Amazon Linux 2 instance, I load a kernel module. I first unload the module, and load it again so that if the kernel module is updated, the newest version will be loaded in the system. I do this the following way:

```
modprobe -r MODULENAME
modprobe MODULENAME --first-time
```

When this container is being run on a server instance for the first time, this operation succeeds. But when I run a new deployment, and a new task is to be placed into the same server instance, the first line fails, with the following error message:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module MODULENAME is in use.
```

The running docker container is already terminated at this point, but somehow the host machine still thinks the kernel module is in use. When I list the kernel modules on the host machine, I see 2 processes using the module.

What could be the reason for this?